# i don't get all the 25 letters in the last line

Tags: java, methods

the output is shown in the image,
i got the 25th letter in the first line.

```
    public class RandomChar {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS = 175;
        final int CHARS_PER_LINE = 25;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS; i++) {
            char jk = randomVariables('a', 'z');
            if (i  % CHARS_PER_LINE == 0)
                System.out.println(jk);
            else 
                System.out.print(jk);
        }
      }
      public static char randomVariables(char ch1, char ch2) {
        return (char)(ch1 + (int)(Math.random() * (ch2 - ch1 + 1)));
      }
    }
```

[image: output]

Comment: notice that you've got a character on its own at the very top; that one is still being counted in your "NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS" count.  I think maybe `i  % CHARS_PER_LINE == 0` is true more often than you expect ( like i=0 )

Comment: Kindly post any text that's relevant to your question as text. The image can only serve as extra.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong boundaries for loop, since for `i == 0` the condition `i  % CHARS_PER_LINE == 0` is true. As a result the last line does not contain enough characters.

I suggest this loop:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS; i++) {
        char jk = randomVariables('a', 'z');
        if (i  % CHARS_PER_LINE == 0)
            System.out.println(jk);
        else
            System.out.print(jk);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RandomChar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS = 175;
        final int CHARS_PER_LINE = 25;
        for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS; i++) {
            char jk = randomVariables('a', 'z');
            if (i % CHARS_PER_LINE == 0)
                System.out.println(jk);
            else
                System.out.print(jk);

        }
    }

    public static char randomVariables(char ch1, char ch2) {
        return (char) (ch1 + (int) (Math.random() * (ch2 - ch1 + 1)));
    }
}
```

You are trying to increase i but the first "if" happens before i++ is executed,
So the condition i%CHARS_PER_LINE==0 at the first loop is true.

Answer (score 0):

You get a letter in the first line because the program will print the letter with a new line since i % CHAR_PER_LINE == 0 returns **TRUE** when i = 0. A quick fix to this would be modifying the loop like this:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS; i++) {...}
```